# Ebean lazy load to see if resource exists

Tags: java, orm, playframework-2.0, entity, ebean

I am creating a REST API using play framework. I want to use lazy loading ( finder.ref(id) or Ebean.getReference(id) ) to see if an enity with a specific id exists in database. If it doesn't exist, I will return a 404.

If I try to delete using an id that doesn't exist, an OptimisticLockException is thrown. But that doesn't seem like a valid basis to see if an entity exists.

Is it possible to check if an entity exists by an id using lazy loading? I can always do finder.byId(id) and that can get me what I want. But I want to do this efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just count items with specified `id`, while your `id` is unique, it will return 1 if item exists and 0 if it doesn't, so you can easily make a condition:

```
boolean itemExists 
        = (YourModel.find.where().eq("id", id).findRowCount() == 1) ? true : false;

Logger.info("Item " + ((itemExists) ? "exists" : "not found!"));
```

On the other hand if your intension is returning existing entity for an example in Json, you don't need to make separate checking, just check if it's not null...

```
YourModel entity = YourModel.find.byId(id);
if (entity == null) return notFound("No such record");

// .. rest of code for preparing API...
```

**Edit**

About costs: `find.byId(id)` tries to fetch whole entity, while `find.ref(id)` gets only reference. Unfortunately you can't determine if object exists by `ref(id)` as it's always not null, therefore IMHO counting elements by id is cheaper than selecting even single field to check if Db returns the entity.

Actually `find.byId(id)` is most expensive option as it loads whole entity, for well optimized   APIs it's usually better to write dedicated methods using Ebean's `select()` and `fetch()`, like:

```
YourModel e = YourModel.find.select("id, name, age").where().eq("id", id).findUnique();
```

or

```
List<YourModel> le = YourModel.find.select("id, name, age").where().eq("id", id).findList();
```

Comment: I wanted to see if there was a way to do this using lazy loading, by getting the reference rather than the entire object. Maybe I am trying to make unnecessary optimizations. I am not even sure what is the cost of  calling (find.ref(id) vs find.byId(id)).

Comment: I guess the 1st option would work. I am using this to delete, so I don't need json. Just want to know that the item existed and it has been deleted.